# Does QT use managed code?

Tags: c++, qt

I have been looking at QT and seeing how ideal it would to code with: code once, deploy everywhere, and even some drag and drop. ([Scratch](http://scratch.mit.edu/), only for grown ups :D) Anyway, is it managed, unmanaged, or C++/CLI for a standard QT form? I am used to native/unmanaged C++ code, and MSVC C++ made everything more complex than it really needed to be, and I could only deploy to one platform. However, being a oldschool C++ only coder, I decided that I would be against using QT if I had to learn managed code too. I realize that I might have to learn managed someday, but for now if I can avoid it it will save me lots of time.

Comment: What makes you think that Qt depends on CLI/CLR or managed code? (The answer is no - you don't need to touch C++/CLI to use Qt.)

Comment: @us2012 I was just double checking because I was looking and I couldn't find anything suggesting that there was OR wasn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Qt is a cross-platform application and UI framework for developers
>   using C++ or QML, a CSS & JavaScript like language. Qt Creator is the
>   supporting Qt IDE.

You use common C++ syntax to code for Qt + you make a use of course of Qt classes, Qt macros and Qt meta-call mechanism, but still this is just C++. Qt doesn't depend on C++/CLI or other proprietary frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

"managed" as you mean it, no Qt is not managed (no CLI or CLR or whatnot). Qt is just C++.

However, it does manage objects like smart pointers and that may bite you at first. When you create a window and place widgets in there, the widgets become children of the window and when you delete the window, Qt automatically deletes the widgets for you.

This is very similar to having smart pointers, although Qt does not use such for that specific case. Widgets are, in effect, smart pointers in themselves.

Comment: More specifically, it is QObject you are referring to, and to say that it is a smart pointer is not quite accurate, more like it is a parent that simply manages memory of its children, which are pointers, not so much the parent itself.

Comment: Indeed, `QObject` manages the tree and `QWidget` derives from `QObject`. Also `QPointer`s get set to NULL automatically too when an object gets deleted. So you can have many `QPointer` variables to one object and when that one object gets deleted all these `QPointer`s get set to NULL.